# Java Spring scan configuration file from external jar programmatically

Tags: java, spring, jar, configuration, annotations

Project 1:

Application main:

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ServiceException {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.register(Config.class);
    context.scan("se.group.system");
    context.refresh();
```

Project 2 (This is the project that is imported as a jar into project 1)

Config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("se.group.system.repository") //Heres where it goes wrong I think
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Profile("Production")
public class Config{

@Bean(name = "mysql")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    config.setJdbcUrl(databaseUrl);
    config.setUsername(databaseUsername);
    config.setPassword(databasePassword);

    return new HikariDataSource(config);
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}
```

The error when running Application:

"Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in se.group.system.service.FooService required    a bean of type 'se.group.system.repository.FooRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'se.group.system.repository.FooRepository' in your configuration."

Comment: is that the whole code you have?

Comment: have you tried add @Import(Infrastructure.class) in project 1?

Comment: The infrastructure was meanted to be "Config" @Jobin no but its where I think it goes wrong

Comment: the problem is that you have a bean FooService, and this bean required another bean of type FooRepository while starting the app. So I guess you didn't define the bean FooRepository.

Comment: where is your FooService

Comment: Config is used in production profile. Did you start project 1  Application with production profile or with default one?